# Sublime text 3065 sidebar root directory

Tags: sublimetext

OK so if i want to create a new project i drag and drop a folder onto the sidebar, after which the contents show up in the sidebar.

My question is, is there any way to hide the root folder (as indicated)?

[image: Sublime]

To clarify, I dont want to have to go inside the 'Wordpress' folder and add the substructure manually to create a project (ctrl+a , drag drop). I just want to be able to drag and drop the root directory (Wordpress in this case) and have it add all subfolders / files without it showing the root Wordpress Folder.

I just find it annoying for example, if i wanted to get into wp-admin the possibility of misclicking and collapsing the entire directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this. The base folder is the base folder, and is the container which holds all its files and subfolders. If you remove it, you have no way of identifying where the contents are located. If you want quick access to one of the subfolders, just add it to your project.

Additionally, with the latest releases of ST3, mis-clicking the wrong folder is no longer an issue, as Sublime remembers all the open subfolders, and the entire chain will be restored just like it was if you clicked again.